# DSGET - determine if no match is found

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in a batch file to return a given users email address:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (users.txt) do (
dsquery user -name "*%%A*, *%%C*"|dsget user -email >> result.txt
)
```

It works fine, but I would like some help with the following:

1 - Determine if no match was found and output a suitable line to the result file eg: `echo No match found for %%A, %%B >> results.txt` ?

2 - I want to remove all the additional output from DSGET eg: `DSGET succeeded` and 'email' and just leave the email address ?

Comment: Use PowerShell instead; e.g.: `Get-ADUser username -properties mail | Select-Object -ExpandProperty mail`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks. I'll investigate using Powershell in the future

Comment: PowerShell is easier, and you generally don't have to mess around with text parsing. Just get the properties you want.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I got the following to give me the desired output:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (users.txt) do (
dsquery user -name "%%A, %%B* *%%C*" |dsget user -email |findstr "succeeded"

if !errorlevel!== 0 (
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dsquery user -name "%%A, %%B* *%%C*" ^|dsget user -email ^|findstr /v "email" ^|findstr /v "dsget"') do @echo %%a >> result.txt)

if !errorlevel!== 1 echo Match Not found %%A, %%B >> result.txt
)
```